# iOS - TableView + button layout (outside)

Tags: ios, swift, button, autolayout, tableview

I am new to iOS and the following question might be too basic. But not able to figure out.

I have a tableview which extends till the bottom of the view controller. I want to also put a button at the bottom of the view controller - (this will not be in the tableView). When I put the button in the storyboard (image 1)- it hides behind the tableview when i run the code(image 2). Not sure how to tackle this. **I want both the button and tableView to be aligned to the the bottomViewController.** Final view will be something like image 3

[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two options:

- Put the button in the table footer view
- Or, in your storyboard, go to the left bar, where you've got all your objects, and move the table view above the button, that will make the button to be over the table.

Comment: the second option is the one I was looking for..that was super simple..feel stupid to have asked this..thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]Here, you can use Autoresizing property form the storyboard.
By using this property you don't need to put device specific framing code.